# using ranger random forest with caret train function results in error: protect(): protection stack overflow

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

I am trying to train a classifier using the ranger function, but need to optimize the parameters by using the train function from the caret package.

When I implement this call:

```
grid <- expand.grid(mtry=c(1,2))
trControl <- trainControl(method='cv', number=10, classProbs = TRUE, summaryFunction=twoClassSummary, allowParallel = FALSE, verboseIter = TRUE)
rf.caret <- train(x=dataMat[,1:20000], y=factor(alldata$classLabels), method = 'ranger', save.memory=TRUE, metric='ROC', tuneGrid = grid, trControl=trControl)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error : protect(): protection stack overflow
```

on every fold of the cv and the command fails.

This is the same error I get if use the ranger function outside of train, but use the formula interface.  Do I need to do something special to implement ranger's dependent.variable.name interface inside of the train function?

alldata$classLabels is a factor of two levels made from a character vector, and dataMat is a 40x23,000 data.frame of doubles.